# How to invert/inject dependency - MassTransit Consumer

Tags: c#, reflection, dependency-injection, masstransit, constructor-injection

I'm working on a project and everything is working, but I have one tightly coupled dependency that I don't understand how to invert/inject.

The problem is in my Consumer class, which will receive a command message to start a process, which is part of a global message queue services project, e.g. `MyCompany.MQ.Services`, yet has a tightly coupled dependency on the process the command message tells it to start, e.g.:

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessageInterface> context)
{
    logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.Console()
        .CreateLogger();

    try
    {
        TightCoupleProcess tcp = new TightCoupleProcess(context);

        logger.Information("{Blah}, {Blah}, {Blah}", context.Message.exampleVar1, context.Message.exampleVar2, context.Message.exampleVar3);

        tcp.StartProcess();

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.FromException(ex);
    }
}
```

`Task Consume` is a part of MassTransit and I cannot modify the signature of `Consume` as that is actually the implementation of the `IConsumer` interface of `MassTransit`.

I guess what I want is a way to invert/inject that dependency so that my global `MQ.services` project doesn't depend on the project calling it. I think I have some misapprehension about inversion/injection, but I'm not sure how to articulate my shortcomings. Perhaps what I want isn't possible. I know I can't modify the interface implementation, but I'd be cool if something like the following worked, but since `Consume` is an implementation of a MassTransit interface, I don't think I can inject an anonymous function from my calling class:

```
public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessageInterface> context, AnonFunc() func)
{ 
    try
    {
        func(context)

        logger.Information("{Blah}, {Blah}, {Blah}", context.Message.exampleVar1, context.Message.exampleVar2, context.Message.exampleVar3);

        return Task.CompletedTask;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Task.FromException(ex);
    }
}
```

I've managed to get around other dependencies such as message type definitions by using reflection and putting this logic in the `MQ.Services` project, which allows me to keep all of `TightCoupleProcess` process related code outside of the `MQ.serives` project, e.g.:

```
    public void PublishMessage(object msg)
    {
        MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("InvokePublish");
        MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(msg.GetType());
        generic.Invoke(this, new object[] { msg });
    }

    public void InvokePublish<T>(object msg)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await busControl.Publish(msg);
        }).Wait();


    }
```

But I can't apply a similar strategy for the `Consumer` because of the constraints I've already mentioned as well as, I'm sure, a healthy dose of ignorance.

If this is possible will someone please point me in the right direction?

More Info:

Project: `App.SubscriberConsole` -> references `App.Services.Subscriber`

Project: `App.Services.Subscriber` -> references `MyCompany.MQ.Services.Consumer`, et al

Project `MyCompany.MQ.Services.Consumer` -> references `MassTransit` -> implements `MassTransit.IConsumer`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am not sure why you think about injecting into the `Consume` method. The method signature comes from the interface and you cannot change it.

You should be injecting in the consumer class constructor. Thinking about injecting a factory delegate is the right one.

```
public class MyMessageConsumer : IConsumer<MyMessage>
{
    private readonly Func<IConsumeContext<MyMessage>, TightCoupleProcess> factory;

    public MyMessageConsumer(Func<IConsumeContext<MyMessage>, TightCoupleProcess> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<MyMessage> context)
    {
        var tcp = _factory(context);
        tcp.StartProcess();

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Then you configure it like this:

```
Func<IConsumeContext<MyMessage>, TightCoupleProcess> factory = c => new TightCoupleProcess(c);
var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
    var host = cfg.Host(new Uri("rabbitmq://localhost/"), h =>
    {
        h.Username("guest");
        h.Password("guest");
    });

    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "customer_update_queue", e =>
    {
        e.Consumer<MyMessageConsumer>(() => new MyMessageConsumer(factory));
    });
});
```

You can find more overloads for consumer configuration method on the endpoint [in the documentation](http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/usage/message-consumers.html#connecting-a-message-consumer).

One additional thing. You have serious issue with Serilog. You create logger configuration *for each message, which you consume*. This is not right. You should create logger configuration *once* in your application entry point.

Then, you either inject your logger, or use the global `Log` object, or use `MassTransit.SerilogIntegration` package and use MassTransit logging in your consumers.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thanks for the response. I knew I couldn't change the signature on `Consume` but I didn't know how else to accomplish what I was after. I did not know this was possible `e.Consumer<MyMessageConsumer>(() => new MyMessageConsumer(factory));` So in my Consumer class, I didn't even have a constructor, just default.

Comment: In regard to Serilog, I use it in the calling application and because I couldn't get MT.SerilogIntegration working easily and didn't find any docs outside reading the code in Github, I just used Serilog by itself, but plan on using the MT package when I start working on a Saga and State machine. Regardless, I see what you mean about a new config for every message. I can just apply the exact same strategy to inject the logger correct?

Comment: I guess this is maybe where ignorance/misunderstanding is coming into play. I just finished implementing your solution, but it seems like it doesn't make a difference. I still have to have the reference to the other project for the type in the constructor and Func<> to be found. How have I inverted/injected the dependency?

Comment: Actually, I guess my organization probably matters. I created a `MQ.Services` project and in there have a `MQHelper` class which has the bus configuration, e.g. `CreateBus()` / `CreateInMemQuartzBus()`, etc. The `Consumer` classes are also in MQ.Services, which I now think is bad design. I don't know if I properly communicated what I was trying, but I was attempting to create a `MyCompanyWrapper` around MassTransit and have the calling classes pass in their Consumer implementations and dependencies, if that makes sense.

Comment: I added a link to documentation where you can read about consumer configuration. Scroll down from there, there are all possible configuration options listed in the code sample.

Comment: I am not sure about "inverting dependency" comment above. What you should not be doing is instantiating your dependency in the consumer. By injecting a factory delegate and calling it to get a dependency, you inverted the dependency. It means that your configuration code now decides how the dependency is instantiated, not the consumer.